# How can I use *.hbm.xml files as input in hbmtemplate for Maven?

Tags: hibernate, maven-plugin

In the Ant task of the Hibernate Tool hbmtemplate, it is possible to use *.hbm.xml files as input instead of reading table descriptions over JDBC.

Is there a way to do the same in the hbmtemplate goal of the [Hibernate3 Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/index.html) from codehaus?

In Ant, I can do this by adding a fileset to the configuration:

```
<configuration configurationfile="hibernate.cfg.xml">
  <fileset dir="generated/xml">
    <include name="*.hbm.xml"/>
  </fileset>
</configuration>

<hbmtemplate templateprefix="pojo/" template="Pojo.ftl" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the hbm.xml files in your `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` directory?  Maven adds those folders to the classpath.

Comment: I tried it without success. The plugin always needs a JDBC connection and I can not override this behaviour. For now, I will follow a different path but maybe the plugin will see an update, if I submit a feature request :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is always possible to use Ant in maven, using the [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). This way, you can set a task in the generate-sources phase.